# Salesforce NPSP Add-on Package

Tags: npsp

I am developing a NPSP add on package these are version of different NPSP packages:
Relationships - 3.8
Nonprofit Success Pack - 3.162
Households - 3.11
Affiliations - 3.7
Contacts & Organizations - 3.11
Recurring Donations - 3.13

And I am trying to upload my package. It is giving me this error:

[image]

All the above classes are from NPSP packs.
After recompiling this page is seen:

[image]

I cannot save these NPSP classes since they are part of managed package. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by Salesforce. Thank you.